# While loop problem, or probably sth else?

Tags: python, time, while-loop, timer, psutil

Soo i am a pupil, and i am quite new to coding. I want to make an app that starts a timer when a game starts (specifically the game Valorant), which i get by searching if the process of the game is running. Then i get notifications by the app every 30 minutes. Finally, when i close the game, the app is supposed to pause the timer and tell me how long i was playing. When i close the game, though, the timer does not stop, and i have discovered that the app never understands that the process has stopped running, even though i use a while loop. This is the code: Thank u in advance!

from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import psutil
import time
import schedule

def show_name():
game = "VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())

```
if game == True:

    def timer():
        game = "VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())
        m = 0
        s = 0

        while game == True:

            time.sleep(1)
            s += 1
            print(m , s)

            if s == 59:

                m +=1
                s = 0

                if m == 30:
                    toast = ToastNotifier()
                    toast.show_toast("Hello!", "You have been playing for 30 minutes", duration=20)
                elif m == 60:
                    toast = ToastNotifier()
                    toast.show_toast("Hello!", "You have been playing for an hour", duration=20)
                elif m == 90:
                    toast = ToastNotifier()
                    toast.show_toast("Hello!", "You have been playing for 1 hour and 30 minutes", duration=20)
                elif m == 120:
                    toast = ToastNotifier()
                    toast.show_toast("Hello!", "You have been playing for 2 hours", duration=20)
        else:
            toast = ToastNotifier()
            toast.show_toast("Hello!", "You have played for " + str(m) + " minutes and " + str(s) + " seconds!", duration=20)

    schedule.every(4).seconds.do(timer)
```

schedule.every(4).seconds.do(show_name)

while 1:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)

Comment: There is some duplication in your code, and the first and last parts are not formatted properly. Could you clean that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the while loop won't break is you don't change the **game** variable within the while loop. It means if the game is True at the beginning, `while game == True` is the same as `while True` loop. You need to revalidate the **game** in every iteration.

try `While"VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter()):`

BTW, You can directly write `While game:` instead of `While game == True`

Comment: Thank u very muchhh!! This was the problem! Have a nice day!! =)